# Why DOM-element is not displayed to selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, html, selenium, dom, button

I need to press green button in to accept cookies on https://garantex.io/
My code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://garantex.io/")
try:
    cookie_access = driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn.btn-success')
    print("Is displayed = " + str(cookie_access.is_displayed()))
except Exception as e:
    driver.close()
    print(e)
```

I have `Is displayed = FALSE`. How can I interact with this button?

Comment: I tried to make webdriver wait for visibility with `excepted_conditions`, but I had `Timeout Exception` even after 30 sec waiting.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to interract with the button by using selenium webdriver, but this button is not displayed for webdriver. What I have to do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The button is clicked with me normally, maybe you need to add some wait like this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

...
driver.get("https://garantex.io/")
cookie_access = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "btn.btn-success")))
cookie_access.click()
```

You also don't need `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` at all before loading the page, maybe after it.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost correct. but that is CSS selector not class name.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
# driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://garantex.io/")
try:
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn.btn-success"))).click()
    print('Clicked on cookies button successfully.')
    #print("Is displayed = " + str(cookie_access.is_displayed()))
except Exception as e:
    driver.close()
    print(e)
```

You will need these imports as well

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```